# Unknown process running on CPU, consuming ~50%

Tags: boot, 18.04

There's a process that's been running on my computer for a while. Every time I restart, the process restarts as well.

I've tried

```
whatis 7063
```

To no avail (nothing appropriate). I've tried sending it SIGTERM, also to no avail.
Here is a screenshot from htop. Does anyone know what this might be, or how I can figure out what it might be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar problem, I ended up resolving this with the help of an answer on the Super User Stack Exchange.

https://superuser.com/questions/1493050/update-secureboot-policy-enroll-key-running-on-every-new-startup-eating-reso